# $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-1}{3x} $ help please?

Tags: limits

So I have to find the

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-1}{3x} $$

I first solved this by L'hopital and got $\frac{2}{3}$ but now I read carefully and it says in my book that I shouldn't solve this by L'hopital..any hints?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the derivative of $e^{2x}$ at $0$?

Answer (score 15):

A "fun" if not-so-edifying proof.

We know:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^x-1}{x} = 1$$

And we have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x+1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Now multiply.

Comment: Thomas,Y  U SO SMART ? :(

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call this a "smart" answer - I deliberately labeled it as "fun" because it is quick and not particularly edifying. The other answers are all more "general" in how they essentially apply L'Hopital without applying L'Hopital...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The derivative of $e^{2x}$ at $0$ is
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{2x}-e^{2\cdot 0}}{x-0}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{3x}=\frac23\lim_{2x\to0}\left(\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2x}\right)=\frac23$$

---

Alternatively,if we are allowed to use $$e^y=1+\frac y1+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\cdots $$

Then $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{3x}$$
$$=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+2x+\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+O(x^3)-1}x$$

$$=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}(2+O(x))=\frac23$$

Comment: Did you really mean $\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: @Amzoti, are you taking about the 1st method?

Comment: AH - that looks better :-)! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, sorry for the horrible typo. Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\Omega(x^3)$ instead of $O(x^3)$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: you are welcome and no problem, my fat fingers are always getting me into trouble! Regards

Comment: @Paresh, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics

Comment: I see! Thanks for that.

Comment: Paresh is right but all $\Omega, \Theta, O$ are also simply written as $O$,

Answer (score 2):

Let $e^{2x}-1=y$ that yields

$$\displaystyle \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{2y}{3 \ln(1+y)}=\frac{2}{3}$$
because $\lim_{y\to0} (1+y)^{1/y}=e$

Sister. (It's the most elementary proof I know)

Comment: I think it'd be better if you mention $\ln$ function is continuous at $e$, just my opinion.